# The right Photoshop tool to remove the remaining corner/edge of a mostly concealed object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

Apologies for not attaching the photo in question, don't wish it to be published in open.

Imagine a person in gray clothes sitting on a dark chair against a relatively light background. A piece of the chair is showing from above one shoulder. What would be the most efficient way to remove that piece from the photo using Photoshop?

In the past I used the Clone Stamp Tool to manually patch that odd part with the color of the surroundings. It worked fine but was manual labor. I wonder if there is an automatic intelligent algorithm in Photoshop to do just that? Those objects in the photo are more or less evenly colored, with sufficient contrast between them, that should hopefully make the job easier.

The idea of the photo layout is below in a sample drawing:

[image: Photo layout example]

Comment: *Any* sample image may be helpful. I understand what you are asking without it, but providing a sample so others could show various techniques on that sample may be beneficial.

Comment: I've managed to draw up something to demonstrate the composition. Hope that helps.

Comment: I see. Are there any workflows other than the Clone Stamp Tool? You mention selection. What can I do with it then?

Comment: Unfortunately it's too late to retake a photo. I have to work with what I have.

Comment: Imagine, if you had a plugin which removes the superfluous, futile or abortive parts of the photo and you applied it to an image of one sitting president?

Comment: I appreciate the effort to include the sample. I was thinking more of a photo (kind of like [this](http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/326189482_1280x720.jpg), or [this](https://c1.staticflickr.com/7/6103/6282407114_e193ab71f1_b.jpg), but cropped) so that users could show actual results.

Comment: @Scott: With someone else's photo you first have to find some and then make sure you have the rights to use them in such context. I figured it's just too complicated, easier to draw up something quickly to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: A photo with rights to edit for non commercial use is *not* difficult to find -- I linked to 2 such images -  but okay :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who finds this question, I've managed to achieve the necessary result once again by doing it the old-fashioned way. First, the repeated application of the Clone Stamp Tool to remove the unneeded pieces. Then I used the Smudge and Blur tools to make the newly made edge between shoulder/background look more natural and not overly dark/sharp. Apparently, in 2017 it's still the way to do it in Photoshop like a decade or two ago.

Answer (score 3):

Select the area however you want and then press `shift` + `delete` (and select content-aware fill. You may have to clean up the edges of this, but if your selection is good this will fix the majority. There's no real foolproof way in photo editing. You'll still have to clean this up, and it may add bits of their shoulder that weren't there before.

Comment: Thanks, I will experiment with this approach. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work well. First, Shift+Delete (Windows) just caused a white spot on the photo, but that's not a problem as I accessed the feature through the menu Edit > Fill. The result was the following. The area occupied by the chair corner was filled roughly half/half with the colors of the clothes/background, thereby pushing the line separating shoulder/background upward and distorting it in the process. So no usable result with this method (at least in my case).